# D3 utcParse returns local time

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this code:

```
import { utcParse } from "d3-time-format";
const parseDate = utcParse("%s");

// code to get rawData...

rawData.forEach((e)=>{
    console.log(e.openTime); // in ms
    e.date = parseDate(e.openTime/1000);
    console.log(e.date);
});
```

and for some reason the coversion is to my local time (GMT+2). For example, when `e.openTime` is `1577836800000`, the `e.date` is set to `Wed Jan 01 2020 02:00:00 GMT+0200`.

Any idea why this happens? when tested outside module with this code:

```
const d3 = require('d3-time-format');

let ms = 1577836800000;
let parser = d3.utcParse('%s')
console.log(parser(ms/1000));
```

it works just fine.

Comment: Unix Epoch is UTC anyway, so I'm quite curious about this *"it works just fine"* result, can you share it?

Comment: In node 14/ d3 7, the `rawData.forEach(...` gives a GMT output for 1577836800000. You might suspect the processing for `rawData` ?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado it returns `2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`

Comment: @RobinMackenzie I don't think so as I printed the unix inside the `forEach` so I know what the `parser` is given and it returns something that is not UNIX

Comment: @orr - maybe some version issue then... per `npm install d3 --save` my package.json has d3 on version 7.0.0 with `d3-time-format` as version 4.0.0 specifically. What does yours say?

Comment: Exact code: `import {utcParse} from "d3-time-format";
import {csvParse} from "d3-dsv";

const parseDate = utcParse("%s");

const rawData = csvParse("openTime\r\n1577836800000");

rawData.forEach((e)=>{
    console.log(e.openTime); // in ms
    e.date = parseDate(e.openTime/1000);
    console.log(e.date);
});`

Comment: Exact output: `PS D:\wip\test-d3> node ./so/so8.mjs
1577836800000
2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`